# Graphics2D.drawPolyline() vs Graphics2D.drawLine()

Tags: java, awt, graphics2d

Is there any benefit to calling `drawPolyline()` versus iterating through each line and calling `drawLine()` in the `Graphics2D` class?

For example:

`graphics2d.drawPolyline(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);`

versus:

```
for (MyBean line : myBeans) {
    graphics2d.drawLine(line.getX1Point(), line.getY1Point(), line.getX2Point(), line.getY2Point());     
}
```

Is the first a convenience method for the second?

Fairly new to AWT.  (I realize that the first one may be more concise.)

**Edit:** I call `BufferedImage.createGraphics()` for the implementation of `Graphics2D`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There **is** an important difference: With `drawPolyline` you are drawing a single polyline. With `drawLine` you are drawing individual lines. So far, so obvious. But what does it mean?

The difference mainly shows up when assigning a "non-trivial" `Stroke` to the graphics object - usually, a certain [`BasicStroke`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html). This receives several parameters in the constructor. The important one regarding your question is the **`join`** parameter. It can be `JOIN_BEVEL`, `JOIN_METER` and `JOIN_ROUND`. It determines how *two* ***connected*** lines are joined. And this, obviously, can only be applied when it is *known* that the lines are **connected**, which is only the case in the `drawPolyline` call. It simply can not be applied for individual `drawLine` calls.

The following is a screenshot showing this difference. It uses a stroke with a witdh of 15 and a `join=BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND`. The left part is drawn with `drawPolyline`, and the right one is drawn as individual lines:

[image: DrawLineVsDrawPolyline01]

### But you should not usually *not* use `drawPolyline` anyhow...

... because it is somehow out-dated and has several shortcomings. First of all, it is a hassle to create the arrays that are required for calling it. And importantly, it only accepts `int[]` arrays.

The whole Java 2D painting infrastructure was originally focussing on `int` coordinates, like in `Graphics#drawLine(int,int,int,int)`. This has been generalized, and the `Graphics2D` methods allow a much greater flexibility here. So the usual way to draw a polyline nowadays would be to create a `Shape` object containing the polyline. In most cases, this will be a [`Path2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html) instance:

```
Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
path.moveTo(x0,y0);
path.lineTo(x1,y1);
path.lineTo(x2,y2);
...
graphics2D.draw(path);
```

---

However, just for reference, here is the code that was used to create the above image:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DrawLineVsDrawPolyline
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
   
    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       
        class Line
        {
            int x1, y1, x2, y2;
            Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
            {
                this.x1 = x1;
                this.y1 = y1;
                this.x2 = x2;
                this.y2 = y2;
            }
            public int getX1Point()
            {
                return x1;
            }
            public int getY1Point()
            {
                return y1;
            }
            public int getX2Point()
            {
                return x2;
            }
            public int getY2Point()
            {
                return y2;
            }
        }
        int xPoints[] = new int[] { 100, 150, 200 };
        int yPoints[] = new int[] { 100, 250, 100 };
        int nPoints = xPoints.length;
        List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
        for (int i0=0; i0<nPoints-1; i0++)
        {
            int i1 = i0+1;
            int x1 = xPoints[i0];
            int y1 = yPoints[i0];
            int x2 = xPoints[i1];
            int y2 = yPoints[i1];
            lines.add(new Line(x1,y1,x2,y2));
        }
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr) 
            {
                super.paintComponent(gr);
                Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
                
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20.0f, 
                    BasicStroke.CAP_SQUARE, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));

                g.drawPolyline(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);
                
                g.translate(200, 0);
                
                for (Line line : lines) {
                    g.drawLine(
                        line.getX1Point(), line.getY1Point(), 
                        line.getX2Point(), line.getY2Point());     
                }
                
            }
        };
        f.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Someone thought that "This answer is not useful". Hopefully, he will post a useful answer. I'm curious.

Comment: We wound up going with your `Path2D` solution if it's any consolation :)

Answer (score 1):

Bearing in mind that `Graphics2D` is an abstract class, so you don't know which *concrete* implementation you are working with, I would use whichever method makes *your* code cleaner.

I rarely use `drawPolyline()` because it's usually a pain to get the coordinates into arrays for pass to the method.  But you should also consider creating a `GeneralPath` object which can be passed to the `Graphics2D.draw(Shape)` method.  Drawing a path *might* be more efficient than drawing individual lines for some implementations of `Graphics2D`.  Occasionally I've noticed also that the output looks slightly better with a path rather than individual lines, particularly if the line color is partially transparent (you can sometimes see darker spots where the end points of the individual lines overlap).

Comment: Sorry, neglected to mention that I create the implementation through `BufferedImage.createGraphics()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics--

Comment: `GeneralPath` is a legacy class. Usually, `Path2D.Float` or `Path2D.Double` should be used (although it may not make such an important difference, when the `GeneralPath` is only referred to as a `Path2D`)